# How can I save the entire form from the client by a servlet?

Tags: javascript, servlets

I create a form with some inputs and other information on a client by JSP,then i want to send the form to the server while a servlet runs on the server. My question is how to save the entire form which I post inside a html file, the html file will be created once I get the request.

```
<form name="myform" action="servlet on server" method="post">
 <input type="button" id="sth" />
 ....
</form>
```

I want to use the File class to create the new html file, but how can I get the entire form and write it in the new file?Thanks.

Comment: I do not really understand your question. What do you mean by 'save'? How does 'File class' relate to this? Do you just want to submit the form data to a server and store it 'somewhere' on the server?

Comment: i mean that i want to save the form and all the html elements(not only the data) inside the form to the server, and the servlet will get the information,then create a new html file on the server with the stream.

Comment: There's somewhere a major design mistake. What's the functional requirement?

Comment: you havent to save the form(html) but just to save data, because the html of the form cannot be change by client, it is generated by your servlet so you have it always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do some javascript to send a post request with a field containting the inside html of your document of your browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  myform.sth = document.innerHTML;
  myform.submit();
</script>
```

I cannot give you the exact syntax, but that's the idea.

BUT it surely is a weird design you are building

Comment: thanks.i have implemented it by assigning many names for the elements in the form,then get the data by the servlet using getParameter function.